# Question has been edited, but not showing as such

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321071/how-can-to-launch-the-mail-app-from-within-my-app) has been edited whilst I was answering (or just after, or just before). I know it's changed (there were formatting issues previously), yet the edit doesn't show. This also makes me look a little silly as I believe the question wasn't originally tagged as [iphone] (as I have that as an ignored tag)

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted

Answer (score 6):

It was probably edited within the 5 minutes grace period after the original post.

This was introduced because many people write their question or answer, post it and the minute it appears on the screen see that they made a stupid mistake. (I know it happenes to me quite often). Correcting these mistakes within the grace period has the effect of not counting for automatic wiki mode (I think it was 5 edits after which your post is automatically put into wiki mode).

Comment: I thought it was "until someone answered" - in this case I believe the tags were changed (unless ignored tags has become broken)

Comment: Didn't know about that 'until answered' bit. Considering this, the question must have been edited edited before you posted your answer. You could have seen that only if you had reloded the page before posting.

Comment: Maybe we need a "This question has been edited" notification then...