# Editing doesn't show "edited"

Tags: discussion, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an editing ‘grace period’ on answers after they have been posted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted)

Is it possible to edit posts and not have the "edited" tag show up?  At first I thought I was seeing things.

I've seen this a couple times, and there are sometimes those jerks that will edit their (erroneous) answers and copy/paste or use someone else's correct answer instead.  Usually happens when it's within 1 minute, which leads me to suspect edits within 1 minute won't show up?

Not that it's a big deal really, but I don't quite understand why it would be desirable to hide edits?

I still think it would make sense to show "edited" but not have to keep track of what was edited.  More like a flag that just shows that, yes, this was edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There is a 5 minute window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted) where you can make an edit and not have it show up.

Reason being that most of the edits within that window are to fix up small mistakes like grammar and typos. Adding them to the revision list would then have a lot of posts kick into community wiki earlier just for those minor infractions.

Comment: Looks like you're right.

Comment: Wait, that still doesn't make sense then.  Why is it desirable on answers?

Comment: Nevermind, I read the link.  I guess I see the point.

Comment: But yeah, there is that little potential problem of a bunch of answers all in the same 5 minutes be cut and paste of each other if they're quick on the draw.