# Question history doesn't show change of title

Tags: support, specific-question, revisions-list

Yesterday, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696498/how-can-i-do-a-conditional-substitution-in-perl) pop up on Stack Overflow. At the time, the question's title was something about "zero-width lookahead not working".

An hour later, it had a new title. The question's history doesn't reveal any edits to that effect. At first I thought the question was deleted and then re-posted with a new title. So I searched my browser's history, found the original question and made sure it had the same ID.

Is there a way to hide edits from others? Is this a bug?

(Yes, I am 100% sure that the question initially had a different title and no, I cannot provide any screenshots with freehand cirlces.)

Comment: Perhaps the title was altered by the OP, within 5 minutes of posting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very possible that you spotted the original title before it was reworded within [the 5 minute rule for edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted).

If that was the case, you wouldn't have been able to see any difference in the edit if made inside the window of dressing time.

Comment: Aha! Didn't know about that. You get the check mark because you were 5 seconds faster than Chris.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a duplicate but I'll answer it anyway.

The reason is that there is a 5 minute window for edits. All edits made within 5 minutes of the first are counted as one. This allows for questions and answers to be revised without pushing the post over the community wiki threshold.