# Why does making a post Community Wiki clear the history

Tags: bug, status-norepro, community-wiki, revisions-list

If a post is edited (by the owner or by people with more 750 / 2K rep), then made Community Wiki, the edit history is lost.

As [these comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37825/what-is-a-bad-feature-of-stack-overflow/37826#37826) show, such loss can be detrimental to the question.

Can this be changed?
Why does it happen in the first place?

**EDIT**: Fixed link

Comment: What are you talking about? Show a revision list as an example.

Comment: I've removed my answer, and changed the tags back.  I can't see if this is really happening or not.

Comment: @Lance: What do you mean? If you look at the link, you'll clearly see that this does happen.

Comment: Still don't see it. Post a properly annotated screenshot.

Comment: @random: You mean, with freehand circles?

Comment: My point is that reading the comments clearly shows that the question was edited, yet looking at the edit history shows nothing.

Comment: @Slaks, with the fixed link I see what you mean, though it looks like we've got an answer, +1 for bringing to our attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't about CW doing anything to the comments or the history. This is about the [five minute edit grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted)

Timestamp of the the question in question: **18:34:41Z**

First answer timestamp: **18:36:19Z**

Between the first post and the end of the grace period we have about one minute and 38 seconds. Magical time. Time enough inside the five-minute window to change the original question post. It may have been switched to CW in that time, but it's also possible to change the entire bulk or title of the post as well.

And we can then deduce that it was Professor Plum in the library with the wrench.

Comment: ah yes I have seen this before... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-uR2tz-QD0

Comment: Don't know about 2:38.

Comment: 1:38, not 2:38. But still aeons of time to add a snarky comment that is rendered contextless!

Comment: Calculating time is only easy when numbers aren't involved. Thanks @Æther

Comment: Woohoo, I answer in magical time!

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing does not happen.

I suspect you are referring to edits during the 5 minute grace period after posting (or editing, for that matter), which are automatically collapsed together.

If so that is [status-bydesign].