# Edited answer does not show "edited" or history link?

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)
>   [Is there an editing ‘grace period’ on answers after they have been posted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted)

This answer on SO was edited by the original author but it doesn't show an edited timestamp or link to answer history.

[In C# how can I serialize a List<int> to a byte[] in order to store it in a DB field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525804/in-c-how-can-i-serialize-a-listint-to-a-byte-in-order-to-store-it-in-a-db-fi/2525812#2525812)

Are there times when edits are not shown as edits?  What are the rules for this?  Or am I misreading somehow?

I know it was edited 'cause I read the original and new, and the comments refer to edits.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work
("Multiple edits made by the same person may be combined into a single revision, if they occur within a short period of time." - currently, that window is 5 minutes - edits made within that window count as a single revision; edits within 5 minutes of posting count as the first revision)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first 5 minutes the edits are not shown in the history. You have time to clean up typos.

Comment: Thanks!  Never knew that and didn't find it here.

Comment: @sam: Search for "grace period" (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=grace+period)

Comment: finding things are easier when you know what to look for.  I did some searches and never would have thought to search for "grace period".