# Is there a delay as to when an edit gets logged in the Edit History?

Tags: support

After posting my most recent answer in SO, I edited it several times: **definitely not less than 5 edits**. However, when I viewed the edit history, **it only shows 2 edits**.

Does the site wait for a certain period before interpreting a set of edits as one logical change, before logging it into the edit history?

Comment: Thanks for highlighting, but I think the question stands on its own, as it seeks for a very specific behavior in editing. Anyway, I got my answer so if you feel like closing my question, you can go ahead. Thanks.

Comment: Stands on its own how? This question has been asked **very many** times. [This one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44174/edited-answer-does-not-show-edited-or-history-link) is the fourth result in the Related list at the right. It is answered perfectly well in the FAQ.

Comment: Okay buddy, won't argue about it. I have flagged my own question for moderation under "duplicates". Comment noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes..

There is a 5 minute grace period after each edit (providing no one else edits that post), in which the editor can edit again and not create a "new" edit, just add to their latest one.

Your first several edits were probably performed within this grace period and thus are not shown in the revision history.