# Are some quick revisions lost?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an editing ‘grace period’ on answers after they have been posted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted)

It looks like if I post an answer, then revise it quickly say within 10 seconds, the original revision is "lost", and you can't rollback to it, or view it, and it doesn't even say that the answer has been edited.

This is fine most of the time, but there has been instances where someone revised my answer as I later quickly posted my own revision, and the other person's revision is lost. I won't know if there was any typo that was corrected, etc. Worse still, the person later may think that his/her corrections (if there were any) were unappreciated, since the errors may reappear in my latest revision (I'm no native English speaker).

Is this a real issue or am I just missing something?

[This is a test edit]

Comment: Only if you're the only one to touch it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted

Comment: I've edited your post; now you make a change. I *think* if two different people edit the post, the 5-minute grace period is disabled.

Comment: @kop only edits by the author of that revision are eligible for the 5 minute grace period.

Comment: @Kop: I'm pretty sure balpha is right. I've seen questions which were pounced on by three editors at once, then revised by the original asker, all within three minutes. EDIT: And official confirmation, too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is by design -- for 5 minutes after post, as long as no other edits by another user have occurred, any edits *by the original author of that revision* are treated as if the revision was originally submitted that way.

This is to prevent a lot of trivial "oops" edits from cluttering up the revision timeline.

Comment: If A posts something, B edits, and then A edits, all within 5 minutes of the original post, what would be shown in the revisions?

Comment: @arjan if someone else has edited, then it's always another revision. Sorry, I'll clarify.