# Is there any way to see edits to an answer that occurred very quickly after the answer was posted?

Tags: support, answers, edits, revisions-list, fastest-gun

As I understand it, edits to an answer that occur within a very small threshold of time after the answer is first posted do not appear as edits from the question page.

Perhaps I'm mistaken, in which case, my premise is wrong and I can accept the answer of anyone who points this out to me.

But if that's true, I'm just wondering: is it even *possible* to see what the original answer was (before the quick edts), or is the original just flat-out replaced with the update?

I guess these are two different questions, actually. So:

1. Does a quick edit to an answer replace the original answer (I'm referring to SO's back-end data storage, here)?
2. If *not*, is the original answer accessible in any way (that is, to those not on the SO development team) after a quick edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer provided [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted/9092#9092) explains the effect and why it is around. The relevant quote to answer "how is this stored" is:

> At a certain threshold these are not treated as real edits, they're treated as just going back in time to pretend that it is the post you originally made. It doesn't kick off the whole auditing trail of you having edited it 50 times.

So basically, yes, there is no auditing or record of the in-window edits. No audit (it'd be pointless to track those tiny errors, even for the devs) means it is as if your latest revision was the very first revision. Or, in a different set of words, no, you cannot see edits to an answer during the window.

Comment: You use too much words sometimes. :p