# What to do if user inadvertently includes email in a post?

Tags: discussion, email, privacy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or)

I came across a post on SO where the OP included their email address in the post (no link because I'm not sure of the privacy concerns).  The address is in an excerpt from a debugging log file, and is in a code block so that only part of the text is visible (the address is around column 300 of the line) which is why I believe it was included inadvertently.  It looks like a work email address; in this particular case, the OP's profile also has a link to a personal website, which lists a different email (I assume personal) address.

What should I do to warn this user (or any other user that makes the same mistake -- if it was a mistake)?  A discrete email to the address I discovered?  To the personal address on their profile?  Flag for moderator attention?  Ignore it?

Comment: @waiwai933: Heh! I searched for "private" and "personal".

Comment: There's a feature request about [giving mods the ability to delete revisions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57925/can-moderators-high-rep-users-delete-revisions-from-the-revision-history), but I don't know if it's planned or not

Comment: @Michael Mrozek, that's not a feature-request, that's a question.

Comment: @devinb Oh, good point, I remembered it wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would flag it for moderator attention with a sentence of explanation.

Warning: the only real recourse is to delete the entire question.

Comment: Does the OP get notified of why their question was removed so they can post a corrected version?

Comment: I learned [a new word](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recourse) today :-)

Comment: Of course you know about this one: "intercourse". It just means "communication" or "contact".  So you can say to coworkers "Hey, haven't seen you in a while, we should have some intercourse."

Answer (score 3):

I would leave a comment for the user. You can also edit the post, if you feel that is appropriate (the user can always rollback).