# Are support personnel email addresses allowed in answers?

Tags: discussion, email

A recently added [answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/17871/aws-robomaker-success-story/18773#18773) on SE.Robotics was from an engineer from a company, offering help with the product referred to in the question. They disclosed their affiliation and a link provided was for a course that they offered. This seemed to be above board, *according to the spam rules*, although you do have to pay for the course.

However, they added, what I presume to be, their support email address, which I [edited out](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/posts/18773/revisions).

But it made me wonder, if the link to the course is allowed, then why shouldn't their email address?

I have read both [What to do if user inadvertently includes email in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61031/what-to-do-if-user-inadvertently-includes-email-in-a-post) and [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or) and neither seem to answer this question, as the email was neither inadvertently entered, nor does it seem particularly sensitive.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with people putting that information into their account profile—but calling it out in a post seems inappropriate to me. (Aside, perhaps, from somebody simply saying they work as an engineer. I wouldn't even say giving the company name would be appropriate—unless they actually work for the company that makes the product.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally no.

In nearly every single case we want answers *here* - not elsewhere.

That said, lets look at the big picture.

The question is *incredibly broad* - and probably could have been closed earlier. The *answer* in itself is practically covering what the OP needs, which is everything.

As for the email address - along with everything else, isn't how we do things. We want *well scoped* questions with *practical answers* that *others can find*.

I'd add disclosure is *necessary* but not *sufficient* and generally its a good idea for folks to do more than "Hey! I'm from $company and we have a $tutorial_for_this". It ends up being a *product recommendation*, which is something we would like to avoid. While it is from the same 'vendor' as the product they want support for, its still not an answer organic to the site.

Likewise, an email, in addition to being a PII like, moves the information *from* SE and the commons to private messaging of sorts.

I'd consider this undesirable, as far as the goals of most sites go.

Comment: If one *really wants* to put their support email, they can do so in their user profile.