# Feature request - A simple credential leak detection in the answer tab

Tags: feature-request, security, popups

I recently [analyzed Stack Overflow for leaks](https://matan-h.com/analyze-stackoverflow),
and the sites contain a lot of leaks (Stack Overflow did contain most of them, but still askubuntu.com and unix.stackexchange.com do contain some leaks).

Most leaks are because users copy/paste code/output that contain sensitive information and accidentally forgot to mask it.
And I wonder, why isn't there an automatic popup that warns users before they post?

I imagine something like "are you sure you want to post this? It contains a GitHub token : {}"

here is my simple implementation of this idea:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prevent Leaks</title>
    <script>
        const leaks_manifest = {
            "Age secret key": "AGE-SECRET-KEY-1[QPZRY9X8GF2TVDW0S3JN54KHCE6MUA7L]{58}",
            "AWS": "(A3T[A-Z0-9]|AKIA|AGPA|AIDA|AROA|AIPA|ANPA|ANVA|ASIA)[A-Z0-9]{16}",
            "GitHub App Token": "(ghu|ghs)_[0-9a-zA-Z]{36}",
            "GitHub Fine-Grained Personal Access Token": "github_pat_[0-9a-zA-Z_]{82}",
            "GitHub OAuth Access Token": "gho_[0-9a-zA-Z]{36}",
            "GitHub Personal Access Token": "ghp_[0-9a-zA-Z]{36}",
            "GitHub Refresh Token": "ghr_[0-9a-zA-Z]{36}",
            "GitLab Personal Access Token": "glpat-[0-9a-zA-Z\\-\\_]{20}",
            "GitLab Pipeline Trigger Token": "glptt-[0-9a-f]{40}",
            "GitLab Runner Registration Token": "GR1348941[0-9a-zA-Z\\-\\_]{20}",
            // add more to here ? // all examples are taken from gitleaks
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="code" id="" cols="30" rows="10">curl myserver/ -H "... ghp_2J7E0dABvrd8DNukfJzJo3tlqXVYcuQGRnOl" </textarea>
    <button onclick="check()">Post</button>
    <script>
        function search(text){
            for (const description in leaks_manifest) {
                if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(leaks_manifest, description)) {
                    const regx = new RegExp(leaks_manifest[description]);
                    if (regx.test(text)){
                        return [true,description,regx]
                    }
                }
            }
            return [false,null,null]

        }
        function check() {
            let text = document.getElementById("code").value
            let r = search(text) // r[0] : true|false , r[1]: description|null, r[2]:RegExp|null
            if (r[0]){ // is leak detected?
                let part = r[2].exec(text)[0]
                alert(`a leak detected: you are about to post a ${r[1]} (this token : ${part}) are you sure you want to continue`)
            }
            else{
                alert("posted successfully")
            }
            
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

What do you think?

Comment: Good idea for private information that can be reliably detected automatically, but unlikely to be actually implemented. There have been a lot of suggestions for different things to warn about before a question is asked, but none of these suggestions have been implemented during the last several years. (Something similar to your suggestion may have even been suggested before.)

Comment: @Laurel I think its sad that it was not implemented. But I added my simple implementation, and I belive that even if stackexchange have only this leaks regxs, it would reduce the serious leaks by more than half

Comment: Related: [What responsibility does SE/SO have in ensuring users understand they may be inadvertently sharing sensitive information in their posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382675/what-responsibility-does-se-so-have-in-ensuring-users-understand-they-may-be-ina).

Comment: If anything, this might be valid use case for AI ... finally.

Comment: It might make it more likely to happen if it needs genAI ._.

Comment: @rene regex beats all

Comment: @rene Passing sensitive data like private keys to an AI is not a good idea...