# Can I delete the history of my post?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can moderators / high-rep users delete revisions from the revision history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57925/can-moderators-high-rep-users-delete-revisions-from-the-revision-history)

While we look the revision history, we will see something like this

```
▼ 2 <br>
```

<strike>securetext</strike> `exampletext`

```
▼ 1 <br>
```

securetext

If I just edit *securetext* to *exampletext* everybody can view *securetext* from revision history. So for the security issue how can I delete the revision history or should I have to request for that?

Comment: Another solution to consider: Changing the original 'secure text' (change the password, etc). That's probably a good idea anyway, since the content has been out there for a little bit already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that yourself.

Flag the post for moderator attention and ask them to pass the request on to the community team who can remove the revisions that contain `securetext` for the reason that you have exposed sensitive information.

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know Mods could delete revisions like that. Makes sense! (better than having to hard-delete the whole post by staff)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Yeah. I've made edits to such posts + flagged for moderators to remove the previous revisions.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - we can't delete revisions. We have to pass the request onto the community team.

Comment: @ChrisF Ahh; OK. Good to know, and good edit!

Comment: Now, can we remove any revisions with sensitive information in them?

Comment: That will be deleted permanently or can be seen by moderator?

Comment: @vusan - I believe permanently.

Answer (score 1):

If it is really very sensitive information you can mail it to `team@stackexchange.com`.
But remember: Deleting revisions is a serious task not to be done lightly.