# Prevent users from sharing private keys in cryptocurrency related communities

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, security

Being an active member of the Ethereum Stack Exchange community, I stumble upon many threads started by new users containing sensitive information about their digital wallets - private keys and 12-words mnemonics.

Here's just two examples I found in my recent revision history:

- [How to generate account address from pivate key?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62790/how-to-generate-account-address-from-private-key-php?noredirect=1#comment75573_62790)
- [Unknown account error while deploying dapp on Ropsten testnet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59338/unknown-account-error-while-deploying-dapp-on-ropsten-testnet)

The community always react quickly to remove the private information from the question description, but it's still available in the revision history. Although most likely those private keys map to empty wallets used for development, you can never know.

1. Is there a way for the community moderators to completely erase this type of information from the revision history?
2. To prevent future mistakes, is there a way for the question editors in Bitcoin, Ethereum etc to show a warning whenever a 64-char word is typed? That it, something like "Heads up! You might've pasted your private key. It's not safe to do that, just use a placeholder". I guess it's harder to validate against 12-word passphrases, but there could be a warning whenever the word "mnemonic" or "passphrase" is typed.

Comment: From [Can moderators / high-rep users delete revisions from the revision history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129646): _"neither moderators nor high-rep users have the ability to delete revisions. The dev team can [...] You can edit the post to remove it (creating a new revision), flag it for mod attention, and a mod will contact a dev to have them delete the original revision."_ The post is a tad bit old but may still apply. I suggest trying that even before a proper answer is posted here - worst-case scenario you get a declined flag, best-case scenario, no more private key in the wild

Comment: @Jenayah moderators can redact posts now, it's not a trivial process, but it's possible

Comment: @Jenayah I would edit that post, but I'm stifled by the non-HTTPS image, so I guess that's why no one bothered to edit it.

Answer (score 12):

Redactions are possible. The UI is a pain so discussing a workflow that works with your moderators is a great idea.

This is no different from any other personally identifying information - as if you'd posted your private key elsewhere or password in my opinion.

The latter is probably unlikely to happen, especially as something unique to a few sites. While there's blocklists of some things, implimenting that specifically that is going to be some painful regex.