# Is data stored in the database for posts that are overwritten within 5 minutes?

Tags: support, edits, data-dump, database

Is data stored in the database for posts that are overwritten within 5 minutes?

For example, if you update your post after an hour, the history will be shown, so obviously the original post is stored in the database. But, if you update your post within 5 minutes and you go to the post's history, you don't see the original post's content... is it still stored in the database (but not shown) though?

Does it exist anywhere else like the data dumps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, anything edited in the first five minutes is considered to be as if you originally posted it that way.

Found the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted/9092#9092)

> **Spolsky:**
>
> > [In the first five minutes...] You're not actually recording the revision? You're not doing the diff thing?
>
> **Atwood:**
>
> > [Not] within the threshold. Right now the threshold is actually 5
> >     minutes. So up to 5 minutes after you
> >     post, if you edit your own stuff. Now
> >     if I go edit it, it's a real revision.