# You last voted on this answer 6 mins ago / locked -- too short?

Tags: discussion, voting, locked

It seems to me the current Vote-Lock time is rather short. (What is it exactly anyway?)

If I scan through answers, and find one helpful, I might upvote it. 5 answers further down I might note that the answer contains a subtle error and I therefore would like to remove my upvote. But 5 answers later > 6 mins!

Suggestions?

Comment: "Vote first then ask questions" < "Read first, then you won't need to ask questions"

Comment: @trutheality: I guess it's about whether the undo-vote feature is to undo *intended* votes a short time later **or** if it's to undo *mis-clicks* a very short time later!

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate of, but very related to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked/80763).

Comment: Edit the answer in question and then remove the vote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Refer this link: [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits)

And this one: ["Vote too old to be changed"... but I haven't voted!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted/18373#18373)

"In general, once you have voted, you cannot change your vote. There are two exceptions.

```
Exception one: you may change your vote an unlimited number of times within a very brief window from the first vote you cast on that post.
Exception two: you may change your vote after every time the post is edited. A new window starts with the first vote you cast after each edit."

If there is no lit up/down vote arrow on a post, you may vote on it.
```

In my Opinion:

1.I think 5 minutes is long enough.

2.If you feel it contains a subtle error, Stack Overflow encourage you improve it using edit function.

3.After a new version was added, the post will allow you change your vote. So, waiting for someone edit it, or edit it by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't remove a vote due to a subtle error. I'd leave a comment pointing out the error. If the answer is otherwise well written, it probably deserves a vote and a nudge to become a 100% perfect answer, or the author learns something from you. Either way, learning happens best when communication happens, votes are really just signals.

Still, there are times when people might argue that it is not an error at all, and the rationale behind their assertion. You might, in fact, learn *two* things from the answer.

Five minutes is really long enough if you've:

- Read the answer
- Tested any part of the answer that wasn't immediately obvious
- Viewed the answer in context with others.

I usually skim through answers, leaving comments (or perhaps down voting) answers that are just indisputably and blatantly wrong. After that, I decide which of the correct answers is the most comprehensive and well written. That one gets my vote.

You can vote as you read, but I prefer to spend a little more time.