# Why did my reputation go up then down for a second?

Tags: support, reputation

While I was editing an answer on Stack Overflow, my reputation went up to 108. I got the "Edit Community Wikis" privilege. But later, it went down to 98 and nothing happened. I checked my reputation, but nothing happened to make it go down.

Comment: When you look at the reputation tab, check the "show deleted posts" checkbox at the bottom. That might tell you why you lost some rep.

Comment: There was only one deleted post, but that was way back in April.

Comment: In that case it might be a removed upvote, but I cannot check that.

Comment: Thanks. I saw a recently up-voted answer that now is score 0.

Comment: Someone upvoted then unupvoted the post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Voting is almost immediately reflected in your visible reputation. However, voters have the option or changing their votes within [a grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80762/168244) without a noticeable record of it. Most likely this is what happened - a voter retracted their upvote (+10).

Privileges are announced once you reach the given reputation threshold. However, there's no notification that you may have lost a privilege due to a drop in reputation.

Comment: ...this may happen when someone feels the need to double-click the voting buttons - a common misconception when dealing with hyperlinks and/or web controls.