# Where is the edit history gone?

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an editing 'grace period' on answers after they have been posted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted)

I just typed a very long answer at Stack Overflow, then realized that I had misread the question. I deleted the contents, put "answer withdrawn" and deleted the answer. Then I realized that my answer just needed a minor tweaking to address OP's problem. I went to edit my answer from the edit history, just to find that Stack Overflow no longer shows the edit history of the post.

When did this happen? And why on earth was this feature removed?

Comment: Needs more EEEEK

Comment: Is this the one? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7435961/revisions

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted