# Why I don't see an edit on edited answer?

Tags: support, edits

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926349/how-do-i-find-the-lowest-score-entered-using-for-loops) has an answer by a user named *pownassis*, which I downvoted because it was initially wrong. The answer has afterwards been edited, however there is no *revisions* link under the post and also I can't remove my downvote, as if the answer hasn't been edited. I am positive it has been changed, and comment from the poster also implies it.

What's going on?

I understand now that there is a grace period for which edit is not visible, however edit should still make downvote retracting available.

Comment: [This might be of use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted)

Comment: Even if the edit was done within the grace period, that edit should have reset the vote freeze counter and the OP should have been able to retract the downvote. Unless the OP downvoted the answer after that edit was done(probably unknowingly).

Comment: I see, I didn't know about the 5-min delay. But now that's an unfair downvote on that answer which I can't retract, because too much time has passed and there was no "official" edit.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ - [Yup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38759/187824)